# How to flip pandas column names on multi level column flatten

Tags: arrays, pandas, string, dataframe

I have the following dataframe,

```
                       AirPressure...                            WindDirection    
Date       Location1   Location2.......Location8593 Location8594 Location8595
2010-01-01 xxx.        xxx             xxx          xxx.         xxx.                
2010-01-02 xxx.        xxx             xxx          xxx.         xxx.              
2010-01-03 xxx.        xxx             xxx          xxx.         xxx.               
....
2010-01-01 xxx.        xxx             xxx          xxx.         xxx.              
...
2020-10-10 xxx.        xxx             xxx          xxx.         xxx.
```

I am trying to make it into the one below.

```
Date       AirPressure-Location1 SoilMoisture-Location1.....WindDirection-Location8595
2010-01-01 xxx.                  xxx                        xxx
......
2020-10-10 xxx.                  xxx                        xxx
```

I run the following command,

```
frame.columns = ['-'.join(col).strip() for col in frame.columns.values]
```

But instead I get,

```
Date       Location1-AirPressure Location1-SoilMoisture.....Location8595-WindDirection
2010-01-01 xxx.                  xxx                        xxx
......
2020-10-10 xxx.                  xxx                        xxx
```

How do I flip the names around like I want above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `f-string`s:

```
frame.columns = [ f'{b}-{a}' for a, b in frame.columns]
```

Or change order of cols by indexing:

```
frame.columns = ['-'.join(col[::-1]).strip() for col in frame.columns]
```

Or:

```
frame = frame.swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1)
frame.columns = ['-'.join(col).strip() for col in frame.columns]
```

Comment: is there a difference in. using frame.columns and frame.columns.values?

Comment: @anarchy - if use `frame.columns.values` it convert columns to numpy array, but it is not necessary, because working same way like `frame.columns`, so omitted, because simplified solution.